# What is the method to switch to specific page on entering theme customizer screen?

Tags: theme-customizer

On entering the theme customizer, it defaults to the set home page, however I need to change the default to a page with ID 45.

The set home page uses a special template and is formatted by the elementor plugin so it is not expected to respond to the theme customizations. The page ID 45 uses the primary theme and is not set for public display, but solely for the purpose of previewing the changes.

#### I tried the following without success

```php
add_action('customize_register', function($mgr) 
{
  add_action('customize_controls_print_scripts', function() 
  {
    echo '
    <script>
    wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl.set(wp.customize.settings.url + "?page_id=45");
    </script>
    ';
  }
}
```

The console error states `cannot read property of previewUrl` but I am stumped on resolving the errors. I reviewed the **customizer js api** at https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/the-customizer-javascript-api/ but just cannot determine the correct process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined the solution using

```php
add_action('customize_register', function($mgr) {
  $mgr->set_preview_url(get_site_url().'/page-tmp');
}
```

Source https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/set_preview_url/